# How to add the same Layout to Layout via kv file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, boxlayout

There is a problem that it is impossible to add **BoxLayout** to **BoxLayout** via **kv** file.

*GTN.py*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class GTNApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

class Main(BoxLayout):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GTNApp().run()
```

*GTN.kv*

```
<BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: '1'
```

После этого выдает ошибку: *AssertionError*

Comment: I don't know Kivy, but it'd probably help to add the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 0):

Python File. GTN.py

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.lang import Builder


    class GTNApp(App):
        def build(self):
            self.screen = Builder.load_file('GTN.kv')
            return self.screen

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        GTNApp().run()
```

Kv File . GTN.kv

```
   BoxLayout:
       orientation: 'vertical'
       BoxLayout:
           orientation: 'horizontal'
           Button:
               text: '1'
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem like this.

GTN.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Main(Widget):
    pass

class GTNApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GTNApp().run()
```

GTN.kv

```
<Main>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: '1'
```